# Какой алгоритм использовать?

Tags: c++

Есть n городов, которые необходимо соединить дорогами, так, чтобы можно было добраться из любого города в любой другой (напрямую или через другие города). Разрешается строить дороги между заданными парами городов и известна стоимость строительства каждой такой дороги. Требуется решить, какие именно дороги нужно строить, чтобы минимизировать общую стоимость строительства.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По сути в задаче ищется *[минимальное остовное дерево](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE)*. Для поиска какового можно использовать [алгоритм Прима](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/mst_prim) или [алгоритм Крускала](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/mst_kruskal).

Вы задали вопрос *Какой алгоритм использовать?* - этот ответ вас удовлетворяет?

Comment: Да, данный ответ меня устраивает